# How to override Http_Provider in Angular2 as AngularJS interceptor

Tags: angular

I would like to have a single error handling method for all Http calls in Angular2. I am looking something similar to AngularJS interceptor in Angular2

In AngularJS, there are interceptors which can be pushed into Http_Provider, so that you can have single method for all your response.

I am trying with following code which is not working for me.

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, BaseRequestOptions, ResponseOptions} from '@angular/http';
class MyOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
/*
 body : string | Object
 status : number
 headers : Headers
 url : string
 */
}
bootstrap(AppComponent,[HTTP_PROVIDERS,provide(ResponseOptions , {useClass: MyOptions})]);
```

your answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To implement request interception, you could extend the `Http` class this way:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('request...');
    return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });
  }
}
```

and register it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

Comment: How do you do the `new Provider(...)` part in Angular 2 RC 5?

Comment: {provide: Http, useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions) }